# Set attributes (margin, gravity, etc...) to an Android view programmatically (without XML)

Tags: android, user-interface

I need to create a GUI (layout+views) in my .java activity class (I know it's far more flexible and easier to use .xml layout file, but I don't want to use it for now).

I can't find any setGravity() (but a "Gravity" object I can't figure how to use) or any set setMargin() method for the "View" object.

What is the easiest way to do it ?

Thanx.

Comment: You can get Details in the Below Link. http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2009/12/setting-margin-for-widgets.html Thank you,Ganapathy.

Answer (score 7):

For setting the margin on component. The following leaves the existing margins as previously set and sets the left margin as zero.

```
TextView title = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.default_panel_title))
final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lpt =(MarginLayoutParams)title.getLayoutParams();

lpt.setMargins(0,lpt.topMargin,lpt.rightMargin,lpt.bottomMargin);

title.setLayoutParams(lpt);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add gravity to the "layouts" not to the "controls". Try to set gravity to any of your Linear/Relative or Frame layouts using setGravity(); .

Eg:

```
LinearLayout lll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutname);
        lll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```