# Android Button Position Programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a button in my application. I want to change its position programmatically. I have created a button in XML as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<Button android:text="@+id/Button01" 
        android:id="@+id/Button01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        >
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Suppose I want to set the position of the button as 100px from left (as layout_marginLeft="100px"). How can I do it programmatically? Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Padding and margin are not the same ... this is thread is what you are looking for
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically

Comment: Let me come to the point...
Actually My Layout contains 9 buttons...so some buttons are visible and invisible based on the condition..so i want to align(move left or right) it programmatically...pls help me

Comment: Take a look at this answer. It shows clearly how to set the margins on a button. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4594374/525541

Answer (score 12):

Luke, use the

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

rel_btn.leftMargin = myXPosition;
rel_btn.topMargin = myYPosition;
rel_btn.width = buttonW;
rel_btn.height = buttonH;

myButton.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to get the view and transform into a Java object, then call `setPadding` on it.

some thing like this would work out

```
Button myBtn;
myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
myBtn.setPadding(0,100,0,0);
```

Read more here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html

Comment: its not working ..showing red line (error) under setMargins function.
I am using Android 1.5

Comment: i have also tried 
 btnTest.setPadding(100,0,0,0); but it makes button of 100 width and text will be displyed on Right-hand side.but still not working

Comment: yeh...this working if i set "setPadding(100,0,0,0) to the Layout as follows:

 LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
 l1.setPadding(120, 0, 0, 0);

Thanx a lot...@Pentium

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `setMargin()` with btn, use it with LayoutParams and then `btn.setLayoutParams(params);`

Answer (score 0):

With `Kotlin` you can use the below:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btnTag = Button(this).apply {
            text = "Done"
            setOnClickListener { finish() }
        }

        // btnTag.setOnClickListener { this.finish() }

        val lp = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
            addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM)
            addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT)
        }

        main_layout.addView(btnTag, lp)
}
```

Note: The layout should be `RelativeLayout`