# Programmatically determine the coordinates of a view(Button) in android?

Tags: android

How to determine the coordinates (position ) of  a view in android programmatically?
I have a button placed in my xml file .How do i determine the coordinates of that button in java code?

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228248/android-button-position-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the solution](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/error-of-getlocationinwindow-and.html) . Please check the link for find out the screen location of the View.

Answer (score 0):

get the view reference in java code.

```
   Integer [] location = new Integer[];
   view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
```

Now the integer array contains the co-ordinates of your view on screen.

Comment: Its always showing 0 value in both of the items of array. Can you help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the methods getLocationInWindow and getLocationOnScreen.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow(int[])